# Highlghting with Shift+Home and Shift+End do not work correctly on Manjaro KDE on a Laptop Keypad

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, manjaro

When using a laptop keypad, using the numlock key to enable Home and End does not allow for highlighting. For example, when trying to highlight the sentence:

"This is a test sentence."

Using Shift+End, it will enter in a 1 instead giving us:

"1This is a test sentence."

This same behavior applies for Shift+Home

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was found on:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=143265

To fix this on Manjaro KDE, you will need to go to:

Keyboard > Advanced > Miscellaneous compatibility options > Check: "Num lock on: digits; Shift for arrow keys. Num lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)